# How to do a custom SQL Query in Django

Tags: html, mysql, django

I have an external database which is registered in the settings.py. Now I want to query some information, but it doesn't work. In the terminal I can see that the query doesn`t start. I hope you can help me.

view.py

```
from django.db import connections

def userquery(request):

    currentuser = request.user

    userinfoquery = "SELECT * FROM 'userinformation' WHERE 'username' = %s", [currentuser]

    with connections['mysql-server'].cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(userinfoquery)
        userdata = cursor.fetchall()

    return render(request,'account_settings.html', {'userdata' : userdata})
```

call in html-file

```
<label>{{userdata.name}}</label>
```

Comment: Are you sure the view `userquery` is running? Can you add some prints there to check. Also, what does `print(userdata)` show?

After you've updated your settings, did you restart your app. It shouldn't be necessary but it might be in some cases...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried it and the print output was not visible at the html page. So the userquery isn't running. How can I start it.

Comment: "was not visible at the html page"

Not in the HTML page, in the Python code itself. That's where you want to check first. Have a look in the terminal where runserver is running.

If the prints are not showing up, maybe the mistake is in urls.py?

Answer (score 0):

cursor.fetchall() fetches all the rows of a query result. It returns all the rows as a list of tuples. An empty list is returned if there is no record to fetch. And you cannot display tuples as `<label>{{userdata.name}}</label>`.

You have to loop over the fetchall() data and then pass into the template.